# Color words ending with a digit?

Tags: css, cjk

I'm working on an application that could help learners of Chinese memorize word pronunciation. I'm curious if it's possible to implement a [Pinyin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinyin) syllabel highlighter in pure CSS. For example, given the text "ma3 shang2", I'd like "ma3" to become yellow because it ends with a "3" and "shang" to be blue because it ends with "2". All words ending with "1" should be green and all words ending with "4" - red. Is CSS equipped to solve this problem?

Comment: Can't you just wrap the text in span tags and use CSS to color them?

Comment: @symlink actually I'm patching somebody else's project and changing the CSS would be a simple solution if possible - otherwise I'd have to implement some extra logic. Is it doable in pure CSS?

Comment: in that case I believe you will have to grab the names via JavaScript and add classes to them based on the digit.

Answer (score 2):

I think its pretty much impossible to achieve what you need by CSS.
The closest you may get is via attribute selector. But this will involve adding the attribute to your HTML markup.

jQuery has a `:contains` selector, which might be able to achieve what you want.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("div:contains(1)").css("color", "green");
  $("div:contains(2)").css("color", "blue");
  $("div:contains(3)").css("color", "yellow");
  $("div:contains(4)").css("color", "red");
});
```

```css
[data*='1']{
  color: green;
}

[data*='2']{
  color: blue;
}

[data*='3']{
  color: yellow;
}

[data*='4']{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- CSS way -->
<div data='hao1'>hao1</div>
<div data='hao2'>hao2</div>
<div data='hao3'>hao3</div>
<div data='hao4'>hao4</div>
<br>

<!-- jQuery way -->
<div>hao1</div>
<div>hao2</div>
<div>hao3</div>
<div>hao4</div>
```